# learning ruby on rails (second web language)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking to learn Ruby on Rails. I already know Python, Django, HTML, CSS, and JS/jQuery. I'm looking for some advice as to how to start (learn ruby, then rails?), and where to start. Free is excellent, but I am willing to consider buying a book or two if there are really great ones out there.

Thanks